# Anchor tag text underline does not come across the page

Tags: html, css

My HTML code is:

```
<a href="settings.html">settings</a>
```

The element does not lies directly under the body tag.
Now i have a situation where i need To **underline anchor tag text** using **CSS**, to do it i am using the following css code:

```
 a{ border-bottom: solid 1px #eee;}
```

However this only underlines the text enclosed in anchor tag. What if want the **underline to go across the page**?

Comment: @CodeiSir did the needful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you might want to do:

```css
a {
  border-bottom: solid 1px red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href="settings.html">settings</a>
```